# Initialize Excel Userform with Variable

Tags: vba, excel, initialization, userform

*New VBA-er*...
Trying to initialize a userform and fill fields with values from one of two leading userforms. Both leading userforms have the same named listboxes with same number of columns, and same data in those columns. Ideally, i want to call userform3 and reference either userform1 or userform2.

leading userform1:

```
Private Sub btEditAppt_Click()
fmEditAppt.UserForm_Initialize (Me)
End Sub
```

OR leading userform2 (buttons have the same name):

```
Private Sub btEditAppt_Click()
fmEditAppt.UserForm_Initialize (Me)
End Sub
```

calls userform3:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize(formFORM As UserForm)
Me.lbSerial = Format(formFORM.listAppts.Column(0), "0000")
Me.lbPSerial = Format(formFORM.listAppts.Column(1), "0000")
Me.tbApptDate = Format(formFORM.listAppts.Column(2), "MM/DD/YYYY")
Me.lbFirst = formFORM.listAppts.Column(3)
Me.lbLast = formFORM.listAppts.Column(4)
Me.tbDetails = formFORM.listAppts.Column(5)
End Sub
```

the Userform variable doesn't fly, apparently. Help? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the form like normal and then you can cycle through the forms that have already been loaded and work with that variable after you find the correct form.

```
Dim Obj As Object
For Each Obj In VBA.UserForms
    'Assuming you only have one form open prior to showing this one
    If StrComp(Obj.Name, Me.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Me.lbSerial = Format(Obj.listAppts.Column(0), "0000")
        Me.lbPSerial = Format(Obj.listAppts.Column(1), "0000")
        Me.tbApptDate = Format(Obj.listAppts.Column(2), "MM/DD/YYYY")
        Me.lbFirst = Obj.listAppts.Column(3)
        Me.lbLast = Obj.listAppts.Column(4)
        Me.tbDetails = Obj.listAppts.Column(5)
    End If
Next Obj
```

Comment: Great answer. Can't thank you enough. Only edit was set StrComp() <> 0